# Проблема с отображением кодировки cp1251 в ссылке: программа = %EF%F0%EE%E3%F0%E0%EC%EC%E0

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка, cp1251

Столкнулся с проблемой, при написании парсера на python3.
В ссылке(поиск по сайту - www.site.com/search=) можно подставлять как русские, так и английские значения и, если со вторыми проблем нет, то русский поиск раскладывается в cp1251

Пример:

> слово - программа = %EF%F0%EE%E3%F0%E0%EC%EC%E0

а в python3:

```
x = "программа"
x=x.encode("CP1251")
```

получается байт строка -

> b'\xef\xf0\xee\xe3\xf0\xe0\xec\xec\xe0'

как это возможно привести к нужному виду?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> слово - программа = %EF%F0%EE%E3%F0%E0%EC%EC%E0

Это специальное представление символов для URL ([Percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)), оно не имеет отношения к кодировке Windows-1251 и вообще к [символьным кодировкам](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2#.D0.9D.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BE.D1.80_.D1.81.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B2_.D0.B2_.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.BC.D0.BF.D1.8C.D1.8E.D1.82.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B5). Из [`encode`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/codecs.html#codecs.encode) ожидаемо возвращается массив байтов — символы исходной строки переводятся в байты в соответствии с заданной кодировкой.

Для корректного преобразования можете использовать [`urllib.parse.quote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote):

```
from urllib.parse import quote
x = quote('программа')
```

Такой же вопрос в английской версии: [How to percent-encode URL parameters in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695183/how-to-percent-encode-url-parameters-in-python)

Comment: +1 за quote(). Хотя quote() использует utf-8 по умолчанию, а не cp1251: `quote("ъ") != quote("ъ", encoding='cp1251')`Вероятно автору именно utf-8 нужен, не смотря на заголовок вопроса. В сторону: о *"в другой кодировке."* — на входе у автора Unicode строка (это не байты). Используя подходящую кодировку, можно из текста (Unicode) получить байты и обратно из байт — текст. Не всякий набор байтов имеет смысл представлять как текст (к примеру, jpeg картинка). Unicode это не кодировка (utf-16 это кодировка, utf-32 это кодировка, ascii это кодировка): `"abc".encode("unicode")` -> LookupError.

Comment: @jfs спасибо, я тоже подумал, что автору неважно в какой кодировке произойдет `quote` и `cp1251` указано по ошибке. По кодировке подумаю как написать яснее, но вообще в Вашем комментарии достаточно полезной информации чтобы опубликовать еще один ответ.

Comment: ну почему же cp1251 не имеет отношения?!
если я использую quote('программа') - результат: %D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0 
т.е. до этого мне всё-равно необходимо использовать encode("CP1251"), а после quote, тогда я получаю необходимый результат: %EF%F0%EE%E3%F0%E0%EC%EC%E0

Comment: @leexxg у `quote` есть параметр `encoding` посмотрите комментарий jfs  выше. Я имел ввиду, что преобразование в `url encoding` и преобразование кодировок отдельные друг от друга понятия: `quote` то, что ему передали то и преобразует. Я подумаю как поправить ответ, чтобы звучал яснее, спасибо. P.S. в поведении этих двух URL есть разница?

Comment: @default-locale да, разница есть, поиск производится только по url, параметр которого был предварительно преобразован. Извиняюсь, параметр encoding у quote, не заметил.

Answer (score 2):

Как уже написали, это называется `Percent encoding`, которое представляет символы в ascii, если они к ней не относятся (все-таки интернет появился до Unicode)

Поэтому латиница не закодировалась в `Percent encoding`:

```
from urllib.parse import quote
print(quote('программа'))
# '%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0'

print(quote('program'))
# 'program'
```

Покажу пример использования:

```
from urllib.parse import quote
url = 'www.site.com/search=' + quote('программа')

from urllib.request import urlopen
rs = urlopen(url)
# ...
```

Но есть модуль, который не входит в стандартную библиотеку – `requests`. Он достаточно умный, чтобы сам кодировать не ascii символы:

```
# pip install requests
import requests

url = 'www.site.com/search=' + 'программа'
rs = requests.get(url)
```

Comment: Какие символы в каких частях ссылки можно использовать, описано в [rfc 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#appendix-A)

Comment: @jfs, спасибо за добавление, но все-таки эти спецификации не каждый читать будет, тем более осиливать, поэтому проще положиться на `quote` :)

Comment: Я упомянул rfc потому что читая ваш ответ может создаться впечатление, что для символов из ascii диапазона не нужно quote() вызывать (что не так: к примеру в пути / слеш экранировать нужно (необходимо safe аргумент в query передать), в query части &= имеют специальное значение, итд). Результат "percent encoding" всегда в ascii диапазоне. Rfc можно не читать, но хотя бы help(quote) стоит проглядеть.